# How to set transparency / opacity only for material texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to achieve a highlight effect over an object by changing it's material color when hovering it with the cursor. The object's material has a texture map (checkerboard let's say). I am using an easing function to animate the material color from red to blue.

The effect I want to achieve is to have the material with red colored checkerd board go to blue colored without checkered board texture. I want to make texture map loose all opacity while the color shifts from red to blue. I have achieved this effect by using two meshes one with red checkerd board material and a second one with the blue material transparent and opacity set to zero. I have animated the opacity from zero to one and achieved the desiered effect.

However I was wondering if it is possible to attain the same effect by using only one mesh with a single material. That would be possible if I could set map transparency independent of material transparency. I am concerned of performance issue of having duplicate meshes only for this purpose. One way to mitigate the problem would be to create the hovered mesh clone at run time and dispose of it after hovering.

Any thoughts on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change an opacity of a texture, but you may change an opacity of an image you pass. Simply draw it on a canvas element and pass this canvas to a texture instead of an image. When you need to change an opacity just re-draw an image on this canvas with opacity needed and then mark texture as needed update:

```
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Well, that's an interesting idea, but I have a concern regarding this technique. If I want to highlight a group of objects with different textures, things get messy. I have previously experimented with updating textures during tweens and I can tell you for sure that after a few canvases opened in background things slow down to a crawl. I guess I'll check this as accepted answer if nothing else shows up soon.

Comment: Hm, I've used canvases for similar purpose and that was not so slow. There's always a reason for slow work. What exactly the problem in your case with canvases? Do you have a peak in system memory, video memory, CPU, GPU?

Comment: I expect to highlight objects with multiple high definition textures, and for multiple objects this can become slow. I must confess that there were other operations involved besides transparency in my previous experiments. I shall give it a try to see how it performs with just opacity tweening.

Comment: For what it's worth, Doing a termporary .clone  of the model to create a hilighted version is a very common way to do this, so I think you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the effect you want by creating a custom `ShaderMaterial`.

Here is how you can hack `WebGLRenderer` to visualize the effect:

Rewrite [map_fragment.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/map_fragment.glsl), like so:

```
vec4 texelColor = texture2D( map, vUv );

texelColor.xyz = inputToLinear( texelColor.xyz );

//diffuseColor *= texelColor;
diffuseColor.rgb *= ( texelColor.rgb - vec3( 1.0 ) ) * opacity + vec3( 1.0 );
```

three.js r.73

Comment: Sounds like what I need. Before starting, I need to read a bit about shaders in three.js and toy around to see what happens. Haven't edited shaders yet, I just read some general theory. I'll give it a try and I will come back with an answer to confirm it works. Thank you!